# When I was 16 I took 30 credits a quarter and my math GPA suffered will this effect my ability to go to grad school?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, mathematics, undergraduate

I took all my college level math courses when I was 16 in running start while taking 30 credits a quarter(don't ask me what was going through my head at the time). As you can imagine I got an average of about a 2.8, in most of these courses....However, when I went to a 4 year they restarted my GPA and I currently have a 3.67 and it has only been climbing the last few quarters. I am about to graduate and I would like to go to Grad school. I am an Information Systems Major e.g. business. Is it plausible to at least get into a decent business Phd program ?

I see that most schools seem to look at these grades in particular.

Comment: Possible duplicate (the question is different but the answer applies): http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/34123/19607  There are also many similar questions with applicable answers, e.g., http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28409/19607

Answer (score 4):

If you were officially a high school student at the time, then you may not need to submit those grades to the universities to which you apply for graduate admissions at all. In general, anything that is done before undergraduate is ignored in graduate admissions.

On the other hand, if the grades appear on your undergraduate transcript (because you applied to have the credits accepted towards graduation), then you will need to explain the situation, as keshlam suggests. Again, though, the fact that you were so young is a reasonable justification for your performance, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 3):

Be prepared to explain that bad term and what you learned from it. Other than that: it's a given that frosh are foolish; that's why some schools run the freshman year as pass/fail.

Comment: Follow up, if I were to retake one of the classes as I currently am during summer quarter along with my capstone and another demanding class to try to improve my grade. Is it better I take the risk of only bringing my grade up slightly but putting it on my last 15 credits or explaining my Frosh foolishness.

Answer (score 1):

If you took your courses over ten years ago and you are in the state of Texas then you can use a program called the Academic Fresh Start.

http://www.collegeforalltexans.com/index.cfm?objectid=6D10C9BD-DD24-153F-90B91DA6C20D1C97

Basically any courses you took over ten years ago can be ignored for the purpose of enrollment. Note that you cannot also use these credits to satisfy graduation requirements either. It's likely that some other states might have a similar program.