# I have a perfect GPA from 2nd year on wards, but a horrible first year... How badly will this affect PhD admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, grades

I have BSc in Mathematics, and will finish my BSc (Hons) in Statistics soon.

In my first year of my degree I failed one course, got a C, two B- and one A+. This was when I was lazy and generally being an idiot. I really regret this.

In my second year I got all A+ including the course I failed the previous year. I got all A or A+ for the remainder of my undergrad. I've completed 5 of the required 8 courses for my honours with A+ and expect to get A+ in the remaining three.

I want to get into a decent university (top 50 qs hopefully) for a PhD program. I am worried that my extremely poor performance in my first year will ruin this for me. Will they be willing to look past this since I got my grades up, or will they just bin my application?

I also got deans list every year after second year, top of my year in statistics, and another honours scholarship if that makes any difference.

Comment: See [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34123/how-much-will-a-u-unsatisfactory-grade-in-a-non-major-course-in-my-first-semes/34305#34305).